# How do I animate the progress of a progress bar in Android?

Tags: android

My current code the `activity_main.xml` for a progress bar is this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/my_progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="282dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="428dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="1854"
    android:progress="1572"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Which produces this:
[image]

Can someone guide me how to make the progress bar start from zero and reach the current point once the app is opened? Look toward the bottom of the screen at https://mechakeys.robolab.io/ for an idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the basic example of implementing progressView

```
<com.skydoves.progressview.ProgressView
  android:id="@+id/progressView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="35dp"
  app:progressView_colorBackground="@color/white" // the color of the container.
  app:progressView_colorProgress="@color/skyBlue" // the color of the progress bar.
  app:progressView_progress="40" // progress value.
  app:progressView_min="15" // min progress value.
  app:progressView_max="100" // max progress value.
  app:progressView_progressFromPrevious="true" // animates progress from previous progress.
  app:progressView_autoAnimate="true" // starts filling animation automatically when finishing inflate.
  app:progressView_radius="12dp" // the corner radius of the progressView and progress bar.
  app:progressView_padding="1dp" // the padding of the progress bar.
  app:progressView_labelColorInner="@color/white" // the text color when the label placed on the progress bar.
  app:progressView_labelColorOuter="@color/black" // the text color when the label placed out of the progress bar.
  app:progressView_labelSize="13sp" // the label text size.
  app:progressView_labelSpace="10dp" // the space size of the between label and progress bar. 
  app:progressView_labelText="achieve 65%" // the text of the label.
  app:progressView_labelTypeface="bold" // the typeface of the label.
 />

dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:progressview:1.0.9"
}
```

For Detail info [check here](https://github.com/skydoves/ProgressView)

This progressbar shows the progress of ProgressBar